# How to identify if any fragment is active or removed on current activity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a bottom navigation view which sets to invisible whenever I activate a fragment...
I would like to set it back to visible everytime the fragment is removed.

for my mainfile

```
 private void AddFragment() {
    bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.mainlayout,new addfragment())
            .addToBackStack("add")
            .commit();
}
```

my current fragment

```
cancle = view.findViewById(R.id.cancleadd);
    

     cancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
             manager.beginTransaction().remove(addfragment.this).commit();
             manager.popBackStack();

         }
     });
```

Comment: Is it easier to do it in onClick method, just add this line bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

Just use Navigation component library is very easy
It do pop stack and navigate automatically
and you can see visual graph,set destination and navigate with safe argument and more

see here
[navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation?gclid=Cj0KCQiAosmPBhCPARIsAHOen-MjVVHf5sklv4goLQUsHbZEWdi_ssVI5kGJDsFPxHx20_Pa761IoScaAlQ8EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)